# I want to use %b.caret as the text of an anchor

Tags: html, haml

Using haml I am trying to generate following HTML

```
<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

I have tried the following:

```
%a.dropdown-toggle{ href: "#", data: { toggle: "dropdown" } } Account %b.caret
```

But that just renders the verbatim text => Account %b.caret

I also tried

```
%a.dropdown-toggle{ href: "#", data: { toggle: "dropdown" } } Account 
%b.caret
```

but that generates

```
</a><b class="caret">
```

also when I indent %b it doesn't work, I get an error message.

The only thing that is working is:

```
%a.dropdown-toggle{ href: "#", data: { toggle: "dropdown" } } Account <b class="caret"></b>
```

But that puts html with class info into the source and I am using haml to avoid that, aren't I?
How can I get this thing to work in haml?

Comment: What error message do you get when you indent `%b.caret`? That appears to be what you need to do.

Comment: Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %a and nested within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it up like this:

```
%a.dropdown-toggle{ href: "#", data: { toggle: "dropdown" } }
  Account 
  %b.caret
```

You can either have content on the same line as the container element, or you can nest content on the next line. You just can't do both. Moving `Account` down and nesting it and `%b.caret` should do the trick.